# I need help on selection statement in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I am not familiar with the advance queries in mySQL. So please kindly help me.

clubs table (has more than these fields)

```
cid | clubname | 
----+-----------
12  | club one
13  | club two
```

members table ( has more fields)

```
mid | cid | name | desig 
----+-----+------+------
52  | 12  |peter | President
53  | 12  |Sam   | Member
54  | 12  |Tiger | Secretary
55  | 12  |Sila  | Member
56  | 13  |Suzy  | Member
57  | 13  |tim   | Member
58  | 13  |dave  | President
59  | 13  |mark  | Secretary
60  | 13  |rita  | Member
```

Desired Resultant record set so that I don't have to run various loops on the page.

```
clubname | Presname  | secname | totcount
---------+-----------+---------+---------
club one | peter     | Tiger   | 4
club two | dave      | mark    | 5
```

I had tried the following mySQL queries, but this takes a long, long time to execute:

```
SELECT c.clubname, 
(select name from members where desig = 'President' and cid= c.cid) as     presname, 
(select name from members where desig = 'Secretary' and cid= c.cid) as secname
FROM clubdetails c, members m
where c.cid = m.cid
group by c.clubname
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: If an SQL query takes too long to complete it's usually a missing index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide enough data to diagnose why the query is slow.  But, in any case, I would rewrite the query to use joins:

```
select c.clubname, p.name as presname, s.name as secname
  from clubs c
  left join members p
    on p.cid = c.cid
   and p.desig = 'President'
  left join members s
    on p.cid = c.cid
   and p.desig = 'Secretary'
```

**EDIT**

Here is another way to write the query that allows you to include the count in the result:

```
select c.clubname,
       max(case when m.desig = 'President' then m.name end) as presname,
       max(case when m.desig = 'Secretary' then m.name end) as secname,
       count(m.mid) as totcount
  from clubs c
  left join members m
    on m.cid = c.cid
 group by c.cid, c.clubname
```

Comment: Edited my answer to add the count column while preserving good performance by avoiding a subquery in the `select` clause.

Comment: thanks sstan, yours is a bit slow, but got the expected result

Answer (score 1):

you could rearrange your query using two joins, one for getting the presidents, another for getting the secretaries

```
    SELECT c.clubname,
 mp.name as presname,
 ms.name as secnam,
 (SELECT
     count(*) 
     FROM members mc
     WHERE mc.cid=c.id
 ) as members_count
FROM clubs c
LEFT OUTER JOIN members as mp ON (mp.cid=c.cid AND mp.desig='President')
LEFT OUTER JOIN members as ms ON (ms.cid=c.cid AND ms.desig='Secretary')
```

and be sure that you have index for the table members for the columns cid + desig.

Have fun!

Comment: thanks omar alves,  until now your answer is the fastest , only 0.3secs, can you please show how to get the member count along . please see the edit

Comment: Hey  @SareeshAgarwal I just made a small change in the query. I think in this case a subquery is the safest strategy despite the query already had joins for members.

Comment: thanks omar, your query is great only takes 0.256 secs to run - fastest from all the other answers that i got

Comment: omar bro, your query left out the clubs where presiddent or sec was missing,

Comment: Hi @SareeshAgarwal, just replace `INNER JOIN` by `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. It will do the trick!

Comment: thanks omar, but finally chose sstan's query, coz the "case" performed better with left joins and was more flexible (had to include a bunch of more joins to get the end result). thanks for the responses brother.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
ALTER TABLE clubs
ADD FOREIGN KEY (cid)
REFERENCES members(cid)
```

```
SELECT c.clubname, 
(SELECT name FROM members m WHERE desig LIKE 'President' and m.cid = c.cid) as presname, 
(SELECT name FROM members m WHERE desig LIKE 'Secretary' and m.cid = c.cid) as secname, 
FROM clubdetails c
GROUP BY c.clubname
```